Trying to find the error in my geometry formula (find out how much to stretch a vector to hit a sphere)
I am a programmer with semi-good math skills. I would like to find the fault in my equation for rendering. The main goal is that I have a origin vector with the length $1$ and a sphere somewhere. I want to find out the amount I have to stretch my vector to have it hit the sphere (it is assumed that the sphere is intersectable with infinite stretching).
The sphere formula is $(x+x_0)^2+(y+y_0)^2+(z+z_0)^2=r^2$ where $_0$ is the opposite of the offset from the origin.
Now, I want to introduce the stretching factor $d$: $(dx+x_0)^2+(dy+y_0)^2+(dz+z_0)^2=r^2$
I took the following steps to solve for $d$:
$$(dx+x_0)^2+(dy+y_0)^2+(dz+z_0)^2=r^2$$
$$d^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)+2d(xx_0+yy_0+zz_0)+(x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2)=r^2$$
$$d^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)+2d(xx_0+yy_0+zz_0)+(x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2-r^2)=0$$
$$A=x^2+y^2+z^2,\ B=2(xx_0+yy_0+zz_0),\ C=x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2-r^2,\\ Ad^2+Bd+C=0$$
$$d=\frac{-B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}$$
According to that, I implement it in the following way:
def solve_quadratic(x, y, z, x_0, y_0, z_0, r):
    A = x**2 + y**2 + z**2
    B = 2 * (x*x_0 + y*y_0 + z*z_0)
    C = x_0**2 + y_0**2 + z_0**2 - r**2
    
    discriminant = B**2 - 4*A*C
    
    if discriminant < 0:
        return None  # No real solution
    elif discriminant == 0:
        d = -B / (2*A)
        return d
    else:
        d1 = (-B + math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*A)
        d2 = (-B - math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*A)
        return d1, d2, (d1+d2)/2

However, the result is always either too long or too short. The middle between the values doesn't work either.

Small convention, it would be easier to comprehend with $x-x_0$ instead of $x+o_x$. Also this computation is not trivial. You should first compute the cone given by your sphere

You can reformulate your problem with an optimisation one: find $$\min {d \ge 0 \mid |dv - w_0|_2^2   = r^2}$$ where $w_0 = (x_0,y_0,z_0)^T$

@julio_es_sui_glace thanks for the convention tip. I am unsure what you mean by cone given by my sphere? Also, I want a "oneshot" solution for optimization since I am running the per pixel per frame in my application. As far as I understand, my solution only gives 0 to 2 values to check for, which is acceptable, but having an optimization equation is not.

Of course one need to work a bit more but then you are sure you have the right solution.

I’m voting to close this question because it was all due to a software problem (see the answer).

@JoséCarlosSantos I can only close with my own answer in two days according to stackexchange

I am sorry for the confusion, it seems like it was an error that occurred within my plotter or similar. After using another graphing calculator, it all works:
See it in work(green and grey with the red sphere)
